# PowerShell advanced function output PipelineVariable doesn't work

Tags: function, powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I created an advanced function to get the mac address from a VM running on VMware ESXi.

```
function Get-MacFromVm {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    Param(
        # The name of the VM of which we want to obtain the mac address.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        $Name
    )

    Begin {}
    Process {
        foreach ($item in $Name) {
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($item, "Getting the mac address")) {
                Get-VM $item -PipelineVariable vm | 
                    Get-NetworkAdapter | 
                    Select-Object @{n="Name"; e={$vm.Name}},
                        @{n="ClientId"; e={$_.MacAddress -replace ":","-"}}
            }
        }  
    }
    End {}
}
```

So far everything works perfect.
I can use it in any of the following ways and get results back.

It accepts either a single or array of string via the named parameter or as pipeline input.

```
Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground"
Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground", "DC01"
"playground", "DC01" | Get-MacFromVm
```

The output is a `[PSCustomObject]` with 2 properties, a Name and the ClientId.

Now the problem starts when I want to chain the result to multiple other cmdlets by using the `-PipelineVariable` parameter.

Normally I should be able to use it like this:

```
Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground" -PipelineVariable pv | % {$pv}
```

But it doesn't show me any results back. If i substitute the `$pv` with `$_` it does show the correct result, but I cannot use that automatic variable 2 or 3 cmdlets farther in the pipeline chain.

Although I can solve this by using the `-OutVariable` and/or split it into multiple lines. 
I want to know why this doesn't work, I want to know what I'm missing here.

Comment: What is your PowerShell version?

Comment: 5.1.15063.483 on Windows 10.

Comment: A bug report has now been filed: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10932

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `-PipelineVariable` parameter. So, I took this as an opportunity to learn about the `-PipelineVariable` parameter:

Because I do not have easy access to VMs either, I simulated the function as follows:

```
Function Get-MacFromVm {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        $Name
    )
    Function MacAddress {(1..4 | ForEach {'{0:x2}' -f (Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 255)}) -Join ":"}
    Function Get-VM {[cmdletbinding()] Param ($Name) [pscustomobject]@{Name = $Name; MacAddress = (MacAddress)}}
    ForEach ($Item in $Name) {
        If ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Item, "Getting the mac address")) {
            Get-VM $item -PipelineVariable vm |
            Select-Object @{n="Name"; e={$vm.Name}}, @{n="ClientId"; e={$_.MacAddress -replace ":","-"}}
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to reproduce the issue:

```
PS C:\> Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground", "DC01" -PipelineVariable pv | % {$pv}

Name       ClientId
----       --------
playground 3c-23-55-c4
DC01       4f-38-42-a7
```

So I wonder if this simulated function also works for you.
If yes, maybe you can find the differences with a real VM object.

Knowing PowerShell, I would question whether there is nothing outputted or nothing displayed. So what happens if you just output a single property:

```
Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground" -PipelineVariable pv | % {$pv.Name}
```

Or:

```
Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground" -PipelineVariable pv | % {$pv.GetType()}
```

Does this return a "`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`" error?

---

**Update 30 October 2019**

As per [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) comment:

*The reason you're not seeing [the bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10932) is that your function, due to not using `begin` / `process` / `end` blocks, implicitly runs in the `end` block, and the very first invocation of any of these script blocks is captured in the pipeline variable, but not the output from subsequent script blocks calls, which would happen with a function that has a `process` block.*

Meaning the correct simulation should be:

```
Function Get-MacFromVm {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        $Name
    )
    Begin {
        Function MacAddress {(1..4 | ForEach {'{0:x2}' -f (Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 255)}) -Join ":"}
        Function Get-VM {[cmdletbinding()] Param ($Name) [pscustomobject]@{Name = $Name; MacAddress = (MacAddress)}}
    }
    Process {
        ForEach ($Item in $Name) {
            If ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Item, "Getting the mac address")) {
                Get-VM $item -PipelineVariable vm |
                Select-Object @{n="Name"; e={$vm.Name}}, @{n="ClientId"; e={$_.MacAddress -replace ":","-"}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which indeed doesn't give any result for the `PipelineVariable`:

```
PS C:\> Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground", "DC01" -PipelineVariable pv | % {$pv}
PS C:\>
```

While the current item (`$_`) does:

```
PS C:\> Get-MacFromVm -Name "playground", "DC01" -PipelineVariable pv | % {$_}

Name       ClientId
----       --------
playground e7-b5-a0-31
DC01       0f-ed-94-cc
```

Comment: With your modified code it works as expected. But with my own it does not.
And that is a yes on your last question, i indeed get the `null-valued` error.

As far as my knowledge goes, all i'm outputting is an object into the pipeline, so it shouldn't matter what the VMware cmdlet gives, which is also just an object.

Comment: The `Get-VM` command returns a `UniversalVirtualMachineImpl` of `VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Inventory.InventoryItemImpl` base type.